# How to increase java heap size for neo4j on Windows?

Tags: neo4j

I want to increase the Java heap size from the default 512mb to 24g, so that my 250 GB ram server is optimally utilized by neo4j. I tried changing the -Xms512m value in the neo4j.vmoptions file to -Xm24000m but neo4j fails to start with heap too big error?!?!
I checked that I have more than 150GB free memory at that time. If I change it to 1024 it works and anything more or fails to start.
I'm using 64 bit java on 64bit windows.
Any help on how to increase the heap size to 24GB!? My db size on disk is 10Gb

Comment: You mentioned that you're using 64-bit Java and Windows, but what about Neo4j?